# Requirement - Bootstrap Breadcrumb needs to be aligned in two lines in each list item and also vertically aligned to the center

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/53wr89od/1/)

```css
li a{
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: no-wrap;
  word-break: break-word;
  display: block;
}

.breadcrumb>li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00bd71;
}
```

```html
 <div class="articleBreadCrumb">
 <ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Inkontinenz bei <br> Männern</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Buy Products</a></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

I am not sure is it possible to align the second item vertically center to the other items. As of now it breaks as per the requirement in my CMS we will be giving something 
 something for the list items. It needs to be aligned vertically center to other items.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options, here’s a flexbox solution:

```css
.breadcrumb {
    display: flex; /* that’s all */
    align-items: center; /* edit */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.breadcrumb > li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00bd71;
}

.breadcrumb > li + li {
    margin-left: 1em;
}

.breadcrumb > li a {
    white-space: no-wrap;
    word-break: break-word;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: .3em;
}
```

```html
 <div class="articleBreadCrumb">
 <ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Inkontinenz bei <br> Männern</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Buy Products</a></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Beck! It is almost as i expected but can you see First list item and second List item are not vertically aligned to the center.
I mean Home needs to be aligned vertically middle to the InKontinenz Bei Mannern.

Comment: Looks like I got your question wrong, see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot Beck :)